# JavaFX How to center JSON map in a Pane

Tags: json, javafx, pane

I'm trying to display several individual maps of the user's choice drawn from JSON coordinates on a pane. Right now, the map's being drawn in the top left corner. I need that map to be drawn into the center of the pane, not in a corner, so it can be scaled properly/universally. If I use a `StackPane` and `setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);` then all the separate regions (they are drawn individually) that make up the map are being drawn in the pane not the map as a whole.

Here's the code for drawing the regions on the pane:

```
public void addPolygon(List<Point2D>coordinates, Color color){
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    for(Point2D point : coordinates)
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(point.getX(), point.getY());

        //outline each polygon in black
        polygon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(0.08);

        //sets the color of the polygon derived from a random color generator
        polygon.setFill(color);

    //add created polygons to pane
    mapPane.getChildren().add(polygon);
```

How can I tweak it to appear in the center? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution would be to put the individual regions into a Group.  Then put the Group into the centered StackPane.

```
private Group mapGroup = new Group();

public void addPolygon(List<Point2D>coordinates, Color color){
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    for(Point2D point : coordinates)
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(point.getX(), point.getY());

        //outline each polygon in black
        polygon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(0.08);

        //sets the color of the polygon derived from a random color generator
        polygon.setFill(color);

    //add created polygons to pane
    mapGroup.getChildren().add(polygon);
```